# How to store a sql table data into an XML file?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a situation where I have a data table in SQL server Database. Now i want it to be inserted into an XML File through SQL Commands. How can I do it?

Comment: Just to make sure, Is the XML file in your local directory? or that is a column of that table?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Need the CREATE TABLE statement, example data, and expected output... and a better accept rating.

Comment: I have no issue in saving the XML file in Local directory.I am using SQL Server 2005 and the table is having like 46 columns of various data types.

Comment: Eg. Create table (col1,col2,col3,......col46)

Comment: select * from menudbf where dll_name ='BUILDERS'  for xml path ('C:\Documents and Settings\bhattacharjeeb\Desktop\DEMO')  Now whenever I am Using this command it gives me an error: 'Msg 6846, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
XML name space prefix 'C' declaration is missing for FOR XML row name 'C:\Documents and Settings\bhattacharjeeb\Desktop\DEMO'.'

Comment: That's because `FOR XML PATH` is not a directive for an actual path on your computer. Perhaps some more reading on SQL Books Online is in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute query from cmd shell with **-o** parameter or the same command by **xp_cmdshell**. in select statement you can use **for xml** option. and results must be printed with **print** command.
for example:

```
SQLcmd -S "(local)\sqlexpress" -E -d "EFEx" 
-q "declare @i nvarchar(max) 
set @i = (select * from [Group] for xml auto,root(''groups'')) 
print @i" 
-o "C:\Projs\results.xml"
```

don't forget security rights for creating file and enable xp_cmdshell

```
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
reconfigure;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no you can't output to a file using pure T-SQL. Whatever client you are using to connect to the SQL server needs to pipe the output to a file.

You have a few choices:
 - [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) utility (recommended, read the XML format file section)
 - [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility
 - Build an SSIS package to do the job (sounds like overkill for your case)

That said you *can* execute these commands from a SQL session using xp_cmdshell.